# Authentication in SPA using Auth0 and clients node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, auth0

## Background

I have two apps:

- Angular2 Single Page Application
- Node.JS with express

I'd like to authenticate and authorize users logging into Angular2 app, by consuming API exposed by express server. I'd like to use Auth0 as my IDP. I want the whole app (client + server) to be made-to-measure.
At the same time:

1. I don't want to use Auth0 Lock
2. I don't want to use refreshes and redirects (for fine UX and simplified flow)
3. I don't want to ship auth0.js library to Angular2 app (to minimize payload and client-side code complexity).
4. I would like to keep auth data returned by server in localStorage (as opposed to passport.js setting cookies and refreshing)
5. Preferably, I wouldn't want to set up database for these purposes, although it's possible.

### Proposed architecture

Red arrows indicate authentication flow.
5 is a generic API request.
[image: proposed architecture]

### Actual question(s)

1. Are there any contraindications to using such architecture?
2. How do I achieve it and what do I need to pass through each of 4 requests/responses? (the simplest scenario and prerequisites)?
3. Are there any resources which will help me get better understanding of OAuth and authentication in general, for beginners in this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1

Given that OAuth2 uses HTTP redirects for a significant part of the functionalities it specifies, going with an architecture such as that one and imposing that many constraints will reduce the number of possibilities you can leverage. Besides that, I don't see any major problems.

### Q2

Given you don't want to use redirects the OAuth2 flow that you need to use is the resource owner password grant (ROPC), mostly because of the four flows that OAuth2 provides it's the only one that would meet your requirements.

- ❌ Authorization code grant (redirect-based)
- ❌ Implicit grant (redirect-based)
- ✅ Resource owner password grant
- ❌ Client credentials grant (aimed at client applications that want to access an API on behalf of themselves and not of an end-user)

In request 1 and 2 you pass the username and password credentials, first to your own server and then to the authorization server. In requests 3 and 4 the access token resulting from a successful user authentication is delivered to the AngularJS application that can store it in `localStorage` for later use.

This meets your exact requirements, but it's not the most common architecture in use. Normally, the SPA would use the implicit grant to get the access token. Given this grant is optimised exactly for this purpose it can be implemented with good UX characteristics, however, it would indeed make use of redirects.

### Q3

The [OAuth2 specification itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is not that hard on the eyes and it would be the best resource I would recommend. For a more high-level and quick intro into the topic I would also recommend https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2.